# Checking for specify words in a grid view in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I want to check if a set of specific words contained in a gridview.

For example i want to check if any rows in the gridview contains the words "apple".
If it contains "apple" i want to know which are the rows that contains the word "apple".

Is that possible?
How can i go about doing it?

Comment: Post some code what you have tried one way would be to use Gridview_RowDataBoundEvent() to track the specific rows with the specified text

Comment: I doesnt know how to start with it.. As i couldnt find any suitable one on the net. I just wanted to check if a specific words appear in any rows

Comment: Do you want to search the current page of the GridView or do you want to find all occurences in it's DataSource(what might contain more records)?

Comment: I just want to search all the occurences

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in RowDataBound if you used templatefield and have controls other than Label,Literal and Textbox then this may not work

i am assuming that you are using Boundfields since you have not specified any Gridview markup in the Question

```
     Public Sub yourGridview_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
         If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            For i = 1 To e.Row.Cells.Count                  
               If e.Row.Cells(i).Text.Contains("specifiedtext") Then
                'do your operations here 
               End If   
            Next
         End If
     End Sub
```

Comment: C# instead of VB, does not work with TemplateFields and might not work if paging is enabled.

Comment: thanks @TimSchmelter see the edit
and yes if the paging is enabled then i am not sure but OP did not made it clear in the question or comments

Comment: Then how do i know which are the rows that contains that letters?

Comment: for whichever rowindex and cell your condition is met i.e. in the if block under for loop you can perform whatever you want to perform on that cell content or you can again store the indices of the row and cells containing your "specified text"

Answer (score 0):

You should not search the `GridView` for any occurences of the given word but it's `DataSource`. Note that this can be different for example in case  of `Paging`.

So i would recommend to do it in your DAL's query, for example:

```
SELECT IdColumn FROM Table t
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%@word%'
OR    Col2 LIKE '%@word%'
OR    Col3 LIKE '%@word%'
OR    COl4 LIKE '%@word%'
```

Then you can use `RowDataBound` of the GridView to change the CSS(f.e. `SearchMatch`) of the row which ID is contained in this list.